# Ubuntu Software Updater: "Not all updates can be installed"

Tags: 14.04, package-management, updates, update-manager

As of a few days ago I'm getting the notorious ―

[image]

Several other answers suggest it will solve by itself on the next day, or trying various commands in a voodoo-like manner. This question asks for a way to find out what exactly is wrong, in order to proceed without randomly running various commands.

Ubuntu 14.04.

Specific error shown in the console flow: 

`E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.47-0‌​ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch`

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and [edit] your question to paste the output of the second command. Then leave me a comment containing '@ByteCommander' to notify me and I'll review it. Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you try to get some more info. Open a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`), go `sudo apt-get update`. When that finishes simulate a dist-upgrade with `sudo apt-get -s dist-upgrade`. Nothing will actually be done because of the `-s`, read thru the terminal output carefully, if ok then run command for real by removing the `-s`. If suspect post complete terminal output for the simulated dist-upgrade.

Comment: @ByteCommander Specific error shown in the console flow:
`E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your source list is causing problems for upgrade. You need to clear apt cache and have official source list.

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean
```

Backup all sources list files.

```
sudo cp -a /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list_backup  
sudo cp -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d_backup
```

Clear faulty `sources.list` and remove its files.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Create new `sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Copy Following content and save the `sources.list` file for Ubuntu 14.04.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Now run upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Why should this procedure be safe or necessary?

Comment: There is no `apt-get clear`, that command is nonsense! Also some other commands really needed improvement (e.g. you tried to delete `/etc/sources.lits` instead of `/etc/apt/sources.list`). And one should *never* run GUI applications like `gedit` as root using `sudo`. I replaced it with `gksudo` to avoid messing up the home directory permissions.

Comment: This answer is a great way of not explaining why things are a fit for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem too, it was the Multiverse repository that had been unselected - by an upgrade to 15.10 try checking Software and Upgrades settings!

[image]

After restoring the checkmarks, and doing the mandatory

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It installed the software bar 2 PPA's I had to fix under the Other Software tab to the right!

Comment: I recommend unchecking the DVD as source, unless you plan to ever use it for that and leave it in the drive, which is also bad because it gets outdated quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what's been written as answers here is essentially a sequence of voodoo. The actual flow I used to work around the failing update, that blocked the entire process has been:

1. In a terminal, run `sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. Identify the failing update from the error there (as no one bothered making the update error show in the update UI). This required some guessing, to derive the package name from the failing file showing in the error message. Luckily apt-mark also offers `unhold` so I could undo my first bad guess about the package name.
3. put the failing update on hold, using `sudo apt-mark hold`.
4. rerun `apt-get upgrade`, which now skips the package put on hold.

After this, however, the Updater UI will keep showing the annoying message this all started from, for eternity it seems.

Comment: apt-get upgrade will throw an error if you aren't logged in as root. `(13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`  I suggest that you [edit] your answer to include `sudo` prior to the commands you left it out of.